# Activity running not showing the views

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have a splash screen in my application which show a splash image while doing some insertion to the database, but the splash activity jiust won't show its view, has this been occured to anybody?

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {

     private ChannelDB mDB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bg);
        mDB = new ChannelDB(this);

        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,HDtvs.class); 
               e.printStackTrace();
               startActivity(intent);  
               this.finish(); 
               Log.d("Splash","createDataBaseException");
        }
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws Exception 
    {

           try{

           }catch (Exception e){
               Log.d("splash","data insert exception");
               e.printStackTrace();
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,HDtvs.class);  
               startActivity(intent);  
               this.finish(); 
           }
       }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/bg"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

sorry, wrong title and description, corrected it, I didn't use asynctask,I just put the creatData thing in the onCreate method,sorry

Comment: Where is the AsyncTask code and also where will it call the next activity?

Comment: Where is the AsyncTask running?

Comment: can you add the async task code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want db creation in background, run it in a new thread, or put the code in onresume. The view will not be loaded until oncreate function is completed fully.

Comment: The view will not be loaded until oncreate function is completed fully.I think that's the problem,thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no splash screen code you have declared in your activity, that's why your image is not showing and within 1 or 2 seconds you are redirected to another actvity.

Comment: but I want the splash screen showing while the createdata process is running, there is no need to add sync or thread wait process in it,right?